# Can't access layers in a Linked File (.eps) in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, eps, embed

I downloaded an .eps from [here](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/social-media-logotype-collection-watercolor_3765844.htm).

1. I've tried File -> Place [image]
2. Then I tried clicking Embeded

[image]
[image]

I have no idea how to access the layers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It may be an EPS, but there are no vectors in it, just a single raster image, and so no layers either.

Comment: gosh, why would the artist even put it on an icon site at that point :/

Comment: Probably because it doesn't even look like it was created in a vector editor  to begin with. The painting effect is distinctly raster-like.  It was probably made in Photoshop or similar raster image editor.

Comment: *Many* people think that opening/placing a raster image in Illustrator and saving it as an EPS makes it vector. They are, of course, incorrect. But they still do it.